# Custom implementation to provide an immutable range of a container without copying it

Tags: c++, template, iterator, collections

I needed to pass a const reference to part of a `std::vector` without copy. I posted the previous version in my [earlier question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/270271/custom-implementation-to-provide-an-immutable-range-of-a-vector-without-copying), thank you for the great support! As far as I know this version supports not only `std::vector`s but any kind of iterator based continuous containers!

Some research, particularly [this SO question](//stackoverflow.com/q/30469063), suggested that it is not something supported by default(at least in pre-c++20 std), so I created my own code for it:

```cpp
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template <typename Iterator = std::vector<double>::const_iterator>
class ConstVectorSubrange{
public:
  using T = typename Iterator::value_type;

  ConstVectorSubrange(Iterator start_, std::size_t size_)
  : start(start_)
  , range_size(size_)
  { }

  ConstVectorSubrange(Iterator begin_, Iterator end_)
  : start(begin_)
  , range_size(std::distance(start, end_))
  { }

  const T& operator[](std::size_t index) const{
    assert(index < range_size);
    return *std::next(start, index);
  }
  const T& front() const{
    return *begin();
  }
  const T& back() const{
    return *std::next(end(), -1);
  }
  std::size_t size() const{
    return range_size;
  }
  Iterator begin() const{
    return start;
  }
  Iterator end() const{
    return std::next(start, range_size);
  }

private:
  const Iterator start;
  const std::size_t range_size;
};
```

In C++20 the functionality is available in `std::span`, so I am trying to achieve this with c++17 latest. Target for my code is c++11, but c++17 features are also present in the project I am using this in. I'm not sure I would go up to c++20 as I'm still not sure how widespread it is yet, but I'm still open to it.

An example of using this would be a member function where not the whole array is visible, although copies are to be avoided:

```cpp
#include <vector>

class BigData{
  std::vector<int> big_array = vector<int>(10000);
public:

  ConstVectorSubrange get_last_five_thousand_elements(){
    return{(big_array.end()-5000), big_array.end()};
  }

};
```

How can this code be improved?
I tried to remove the dependent typename, but I could only do that with C++20 `std::iter_reference_t`. Is there no other way to deduce `T` explicitly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With C++17 the compiler should be able to deduce the template type automatically by using the following:

```
template <typename Iterator>
class ConstVectorSubrange {
public:
    using T = typename Iterator::value_type;
    // ...
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector v{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    ConstVectorSubrange range(v.begin() + 2, v.end() - 2);
}
```

I'm not sure why you have included `<iterator>` and failed to include `<cassert>`?

Good:

I like that you can now use the foreach loop:

```
std::vector v{ 7, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9 };
ConstVectorSubrange vsr(v.begin() + 4, v.end());
for (int i : vsr)
    std::cout << i << "\n";
```

And all the cool stuff from `<algorithm>`

```
std::cout << std::count(vsr.begin(), vsr.end(), 7) << "\n";
```

Ideas:

It would be pretty cool if you could include a `step` or `stride` to have a slice of the vector. Something like this:

```
std::vector v{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
std::size_t step = 2;
ConstVectorSubrange r(v.begin() + 1, v.end(), step);
for (int i : r)
    std::cout << i << "\n";
// expected results 2, 4, 6
```

Comment: `<assert.h>` is not a C++ header. You probably mean `<cassert>`.

Comment: @indi thanks, updated.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @DavidTóth, cool! You got so close that I almost feel like I should have added a spoiler alert ;-)